# Visual Studio linker can't open 'Debug/myapp.exe'

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I'm getting the following linker error sometimes when I make a change and try to run my program:

1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Debug\myapp.exe'

I am able to run it sometimes, but then it gets stuck with this error on build for up to a day at a time.  I looked through the other threads on it, and the issue there was either that it's already running, or the virus scan is taking control of it.  Neither solution has helped, and I only started experiencing this a week or so ago, so this might be because of a new update.  I'm using Windows 10 and Webroot for virus scanning, with VS22 as the compiler.

The "process is running" fixes I've attempted are:

1. taskkill /IM myapp.exe /F -> ERROR: The process "myapp.exe" not found.
2. "myapp.exe" is not showing up in "Task Manager" (under Apps nor Processes)
3. It does not show up in "Resource Monitor"
4. It does not show up in "Process Explorer"

For the virus scanner, I added the following exceptions:

1. In Webroot, it's set as an "Allowed File" in the "PC Security" settings
2. In Windows "Virus & Threat Protection", I've added these exclusions:

- File Exclusion -> C:...\Debug\myapp.exe (the "..." contains the remaining portions of the path)
- Process Exclusion -> myapp
- Process Exclusion -> myapp.exe

I also have tried restarting my system, but the issue persists after a restart.  I haven't set it as a startup application.  Given time, I'm able to compile and run the program just fine, but then it becomes unusable again within about 10 minutes.  I've also tried completely disabling my virus software (both MS and Webroot) and the issue still occurs.  Is there anything else that might be getting a hold on the "myapp.exe" file?

Comment: The issue looks to be with VS22 itself.  I found that I can workaround with the following:

1. Restart computer
2. In the project's directory, delete the ".vs" and "Debug" folders
3. Restart VS22 and rebuild

It works for a while, but the process must be repeated every 20 minutes or so.  Is there a feature in VS22 that's causing this which I can disable?